Error: unable to verify the first certificate
Tengo una aplicación web desarrollada en NodeJS y ubicada en AWS bajo un nginx que hace peticiones a otro servidor NodeJS (motor de reglas) que está ubicado en la misma máquina, pero en otro proceso PM2.
Estoy tratando de añadir un WAF y un balanceador de carga a la aplicación web, pero al hacer las peticiones al motor de reglas, devuelve el error  Error: unable to verify the first certificate.
Aparentemente, el balanceador de carga tiene añadidos los certificados correctamente, por lo que no sé por dónde está llegando el error, si por la parte de NodeJS o por AWS.
Me gustaría que me ayudarais al menos a identificar por dónde puede estar la raíz del problema, o qué información necesitáis (disculpad, pero soy novata en infraestructuras), ya que antes de añadir el balanceador ambos servidores se comunicaban correctamente, pero al cambiar el dominio por la IP para la configuración del balanceador, surgió este error.
